I lost one of 12 words of my 12 phrase seed
I lost my 12th word of my trust wallet 12 seed phrase. I just have phone. I don't have a PC. I’m using trustwallet, multi chain wallet. How can I recover my wallet?

This question is similar to: I have 23 words of my 24 word mnemonic (and passphrase) for my ledger nano-s, is it possible for me to brute-force the last word (not in order). If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Also see Wallet recovery phrase
